# Get sql server data in ubuntu

Tags: connection, sql

How can I get Sql server's data in ubuntu. I have recently shifted from windows where we had Sql server management studio to do this task. Is there an alternative of it in ubuntu.
I know some different versions of this questions have been asked but they don't satisfy my need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is no better way other than using a virtual environments etc. on ubuntu.

Edit:

Install a virtual environment and install Windows
Use that to install SQL Server Management studio and use accordingly.

Comment: You mean running that studio in a vm?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit "vague" on how can you get SQL server's data in Ubuntu.

But answering it in a simple manner, there are many tools in the wild that you can choose from for connecting to your SQL server, most if not all are CLI based but the one's most common tool is called `sqlcmd` which can be installed by  following this article: https://www.tecmint.com/install-ms-sql-server-centos-ubuntu-linux/

Shifting from GUI to CLI is a bit hard to adapt to or accept at first.